# How can I logs all Realm database accesses?

Tags: ios, realm

I have a bug in my Realm-based iOS app where objects suddenly disappears and I can't figure out why.

In order to track the bug, I would like to log all changes to the db (like insertions, changes and deletions).

I can't find any way of doing that in the official Realm Documentation.

Is there any hidden feature to write such logs ? Or perhaps a third-party library ?

Comment: Are you not using realm command prompt file (start-object-server.command)? Its logs everything.

Comment: This is not about a server-based Realm but just mobile DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this, and I'm not aware of any third-party tools that provide this specific functionality. You may be able to achieve what you're after using [DTrace's support for tracing Objective-C](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/hooked-on-dtrace-part-3/), but it'll be somewhat involved.